# Non-sense in pySpark calculation using a lambda over a Row

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have a df in pyspark representing KM run by cars by day.

Explanation of fields:

x[3] is the day of the week in Italian, i.e:

```
LUN (MON)
MAR (TUE)
MER (WED)
GIO (THU)
VEN (FRI)
SAB (SAT)
DOM (SUN)
```

X[22] are the kilometers in night hours

X[23] are the kilometers in day time

The objective is to insert 3 new columns. In pseudo code:

```
km_totali  (total km): x[22]+x[23] 
km_festivo (week-end km): x[22]+x[23] if x[3] in [SAB, DOM] i.e. SAT or SUN; else 0
km_feriale (weekday km): x[22]+x[23]  if x[3] in [LUN-VEN]. i.e. MON-FRI; else 0
```

In other words, km_totali should always be calculated.
km_festivo should be equal to km_totali on the weekend days, 0 otherwise
km_feriale should be equal to km_totali on the week-days, 0 otherwise.

This is my code:

```
new_df=df.rdd.map(lambda x: Row(
                                giorno_della_settimana=x[3],
                                km_totali=x[22]+x[23],
                                km_feriale=x[22]+x[23] if x[3] in ["LUN","MAR", "MER", "GIO", "VEN] else 0,
                                km_festivo=x[22]+x[23] if x[3] in ["SAB","DOM"] else 0
                                )).toDF()
```

As you can see in the below output, km_totali is ALWAYS calculated (and it is correct, I made my checks). It also correctly caluclates  km_festivo  and km_feriale during week-days (MER and MON in the below example). But it ALWAYS fails to calulate km_festivo and km_feriale during week-end days (Nones in the DOM line in the below example).

OUTPUT:

```
Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'DOM', km_feriale=None, km_festivo=None, km_totali=106.5),
Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'MER', km_feriale=8.2, km_festivo=0, km_totali=8.2),
Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'LUN', km_feriale=3.0, km_festivo=0, km_totali=3.0),
```

Notice that km_totali is correctly calculated also in the "DOM" case. In facts, th desired output for the DOM line would be:

```
Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'DOM', km_feriale=0, km_festivo=106.5, km_totali=106.5)
```

What it drives me completely crazy is that If I extend the list of days in the km_festivo's condition list to the whole week (meaningless from a semantic point of view), the km_festivo field gets correctly calculated also in the DOM line:

```
new_df=df.map(lambda x: Row(
                            giorno_della_settimana=x[3],
                            km_totali=x[22]+x[23],
                            km_feriale=x[22]+x[23] if x[3] in ["LUN","MAR", "MER","GIO", "VEN"] else 0,
                 extended-> km_festivo=x[22]+x[23] if x[3] in ["LUN","MAR", "MER","GIO", "VEN","SAB","DOM"] else 0
                                                                                           
                             )).toDF()
```

OUTPUT for the DOM line:

```
Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'DOM', km_feriale=None, km_festivo=106.5, km_totali=106.5),
```

As you can see, the  km_festivo is now calculated for the DOM line (i.e a week-end day) ONLY because I have included Week-days in the condition list.  This is a nonsense!

I feel this is is not a matter of coding but I cannot figure out what this could possibly due to.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
In the else clause, I have to return 0.0 instead of 0.
Otherwise I have a column with mixed types. Somtimes floats and somtimes integers

This is the right code:

```
new_df=df.rdd.map(lambda x: Row(
                            giorno_della_settimana=x[3],
                            km_totali=x[22]+x[23],
                            km_feriale=x[22]+x[23] if x[3] in ["LUN","MAR", "MER", "GIO", "VEN] else 0.0,
                            km_festivo=x[22]+x[23] if x[3] in ["SAB","DOM"] else 0.0
                            )).toDF()
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution! Data types are better handled within pyspark, not using UDF has the other advantage of working faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide sample data?

I don't see anything wrong with your code apart from the fact that you're doing redundant computations (x[22] +x[23] at least twice) instead of computing it afterwards.

Could you try:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
new_df = df.map(lambda x: Row(
    giorno_della_settimana=x[3],
    km_totali=x[22]+x[23]
)).toDF()

new_df2 = new_df.select(
    "*", 
    psf.when(new_df.giorno_della_settimana.isin(["LUN","MAR", "MER","GIO", "VEN"]), new_df.km_totali).otherwise(0).alias("km_feriale"), 
    psf.when(new_df.giorno_della_settimana.isin(["SAB","DOM"]), new_df.km_totali).otherwise(0).alias("km_festivo"), 
)
```

Comment: Hi, your way works perfectly. These are some examples of your code's output.   
 Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'SAB', km_feriale=None, km_festivo=None, km_totali=3.7, km_feriale=0.0, km_festivo=3.7),
 Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'MER', km_feriale=116.7, km_festivo=0, km_totali=116.7, km_feriale=116.7, km_festivo=0.0),
 Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'MER', km_feriale=4.8, km_festivo=0, km_totali=4.8, km_feriale=4.8, km_festivo=0.0),
 Row(giorno_della_settimana=u'MER', km_feriale=15.4, km_festivo=0, km_totali=15.4, km_feriale=15.4, km_festivo=0.0),

Comment: You still get `None` for `"SAB"`? Could you provide a sample of the original dataframe (just the needed columns `df.select(...).show()`) and add it to your question. I realize now that you were already working on a dataframe and not an RDD, you should have to switch to RDD for such simple operations but still it doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: [u'MER', 0.0, 0.0],
 [u'MER', 19.4, 0.0],
 [u'MER', 0.6, 0.0],
 [u'MER', 22.1, 10.5],
 [u'MER', 24.8, 0.0],
 [u'MER', 0.0, 0.0],
 [u'MER', 11.9, 0.0],
 [u'MAR', 0.0, 0.0],
 [u'SAB', 29.2, 1.4000000000000001],
 [u'SAB', 48.9, 15.8],
 [u'SAB', 70.0, 0.0],
 [u'SAB', 23.7, 0.0],
 [u'SAB', 5.7, 0.0],
 [u'SAB', 9.2, 0.0],
 [u'SAB', 277.9, 0.0],
 [u'SAB', 5.6, 4.6],
 [u'SAB', 23.7, 0.6],
 [u'SAB', 4.8, 6.0],
 [u'SAB', 2.8000000000000003, 0.0]

Comment: This is a sample. The crazy thing is that for MER lines it works fine. For SAB line it does not!